# Python SQLalchemy Multiple fields of a table

Tags: python, mysql, sql, sqlalchemy

I have a problem with SQL Alchemy, while trying to think about an SQL schema I encountered the following problem.

My schema is based on 2 classes, Flight and Trip.

A Trip includes 2 fields: flights_to and flights_from.
Any of the fields is basically a list of flights, it could be made of one flight, or many flights (Connection flights).

```
class Trip(Base):
    __tablename__ = "Trip"
    __table_args__ = {'sqlite_autoincrement': True}
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
    flights_to = relationship("Flight", backref="Trip")
    flights_from = relationship("Flight", backref="Trip")

class Flight(Base):
    __tablename__ = "Flight"
    __table_args__ = {'sqlite_autoincrement': True}
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
    arrival_airport = Column(String(20))
    departure_airport = Column(String(20))
    flight_number = Column(Integer)
    trip_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('Trip.id'))
```

The problem happens when I create 2 fields in the same type:

> sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Error creating backref 'Trip' on relationship 'Trip.flights_from': property of that name exists on mapper 'Mapper|Flight|Flight'

I have thought about using 2 inheriting classes of types FlightTo and FlightFrom and saving them at two different tables, but what if I want to use a FlightFrom as a FlightTo? will the flight be duplicated in 2 tables?

I would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

`backref` is used to define a new property on the other class you are using relationship with. So you can't have two property which have the same name

You should rename your `backref` for the flights_from to any other name than `Trip`.

It will work then.

For Example:

```
class Person(Model):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    address = relationship("Address",backref="address")

class Address(Model):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    house_no = Column(Integer)
    person_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('person.id'))
```

So you can access the person name with house_no 100 by:

```
query_address = Address.query.filter_by(house_no=100).first()

person = query_address.address
```

This returns you the `person` object.
Thus if you have multiple such names , it will give you an error

Comment: I don't think you understood the question, backref is not even necessary here because referencing is made from Trip to the flight only

Comment: Well what I have tried to explain is why you have got the error. To be more explicit, as the error mentions that it can't create a back reference with the name "Trip" on flights from because the back reference '"Trip" has already been taken by flights_to. In my answer , the second part I have just tried to show an example.The error shall go if you rename flights_from back reference.